# Fortran module with MinGW used with MSVC causes unresolved symbol "__exmod_MOD_value"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fortran, gfortran

I would like to use a Fortran library on Windows, which contains many modules. Therefore I need to compile this library with MinGW. For using the MSVC compiler I need to compile the library with external links as mentioned in these two links:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/s8CiQnNmO14
https://blog.kitware.com/fortran-for-cc-developers-made-easier-with-cmake/

This seems to work as long as I do not use modules.

Here is a minimal example:

Fortran code:

```
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------!
!                                                                         !
!     MODULE EXMOD                                                        !
!                                                                         !
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------!
MODULE EXMOD
  INTEGER                                        :: VALUE

CONTAINS

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------!
!                                                                         !
!     INITOPTMOD                                                          !
!                                                                         !
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------!
SUBROUTINE INITOPTMOD(VALUE_IN)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER, INTENT(IN)                             :: VALUE_IN
  VALUE = VALUE_IN
  WRITE(*,*) 'The Value is: ', VALUE
  RETURN
END SUBROUTINE INITOPTMOD
END MODULE EXMOD
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------!

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------!
!                                                                         !
!     EXTERN CALLER                                                       !
!                                                                         !
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------!
SUBROUTINE FORTCALL( VALUE_ )
    USE EXMOD
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN)                      :: VALUE_
    CALL INITOPTMOD(VALUE_)
END SUBROUTINE FORTCALL
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------!
```

I compiled this with:

```
gfortran forfunc.f90 -c
gfortran -o libfortfunc.dll forfunc.o -shared -Wl,--output-def,libfortfunc.def
lib /MACHINE:x64 /def:libfortfunc.def /out:libfortfunc.lib
```

After compiling the library I tried to compile the main.cpp with MSVC:

main.cpp:

```
extern "C" {
    void fortcall_( int *value );
}

int main()
{

    int value = 12;

    fortcall_( &value );
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile this with:

```
cl main.cpp libfortfunc.exp libfortfunc.lib
```

If there is no module this works fine, but since the fortran code contains one the following error occurs:

```
/out:main.exe
main.obj
libfortfunc.exp
libfortfunc.lib
libfortfunc.exp : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__exmod_MOD_value".
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 nicht aufgelöste Externe
```

Can I do something to fix that?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Fortran 90 is just one old version. You can use a version tag to specify a version specific question, but that is not this case. You will gat much more atention from more people.

Comment: Where is module `OPTMOD` defined? The error message is looking for that one. It cannot find symbol VALUE from module OPTMOD.

Comment: The module was called OPTMOD I renamed it to EXMOD for this post. Sorry...

Comment: But than the error message is inconsistent. Is everything in one source file? Shouldn't you be linking with the dll as well or just the lib? (I am not sure, I do not use Windows.)

Comment: I tried to implement the code very simular to the first link. Except the module. The fortran code is in the file forfunc.f90 and the main in main.cpp. (I usually do not use Windows too, but I have to connect my programs to something, that is running on Windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I found a way to avoid this error.
I had a look at the file libfortfunc.def:

```
EXPORTS
    __exmod_MOD_initoptmod @1
    __exmod_MOD_value @2 DATA
    fortcall_ @3
```

Since i do not want to use the modules from my C++ code I simply deleted all exports from the module. After that I run the commands:

```
lib /MACHINE:x64 /def:libfortfunc.def /out:libfortfunc.lib
cl main.cpp libfortfunc.exp libfortfunc.lib
```

That works fine and the main.exe file returns the right value.
Since this does not feel like the right way to do it, the remaining questions are:

How can I tell gfortran that it must not export modules?

Why is exporting modules a problem?